# Huge delay in network communication

Tags: c#, sockets, networking, delay

I ame writing a wcf like application, a client sends some data to a server with an id and some packet handeling data, and the server sends a message back with the same id, i ame testing the client and server on thesame computer, i ame not using localhost to connect the server and client together but the real ip address so it wil actualy open a socket instead of a loopback(this is wat i have heared). now i get amazing response times , 500(.05ms)-1000(.1ms) ticks for a : `client-> server-> client` communication, now i want to try it from computer to computer, so i run the client on one and the server on the other, but now the time to communicate increases ALOT, i now get times from 250000(25ms) to 350000(35ms) ticks, why does this happen? i tried using the debugger to find any delays, but i realy only get alot of delay in the socket communication

this is the initalisation of the server socket:

```
IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(LocalIpAddress), port);
        Listener = new Socket(localEndPoint.Address.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        Listener.Bind(localEndPoint);
        Listener.LingerState = new LingerOption(false, 0);
        Listener.Listen(0);
```

this is the initialisation of the client socket:

```
ClientSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        ClientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize = buffer.Length;
        ClientSocket.LingerState = new LingerOption(false, 0);
```

Comment: Is this not just the added latency of having to communicate over a network infrastructure? I am not entirely sure what 250000 ticks translates to in standard time, how many milliseconds in this?

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth i've added the time in ms (1 ms = 10000 ticks). yes that is what i thought too, but 35ms? it maby are 40 bytes that are send, and what i know when testing on the local computer it does communicate via the network.

Comment: Without knowing the topology and hardware in between your two computers, I couldn't say whether that many milliseconds are surprising or not. However, the story tends that latency exists. You'd be best off expecting it and working with it than trying to always make it fast enough that your app doesn't need to worry about it (nice to aim for, but unfortunately it can be unrealistic).

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth, it is a gig network that is unused except my 2 computers, i just realised that the sockets can wait for data if it is a small packet, so it will wait with sending of the packet for a while. ive now tryed to let it send it directley, and i ame now getting responsetimes of about 5000 ticks(.5 ms). il try to improve it some more and il let it know here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seem to have somthing to do with the attached debugger, whenever i run the program with the debugger attached i get strange and unexplained delays, when i run the program stand alone as an excecutable i get no delays what so ever.